# Write Condition as a value for the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable called `_gender` thats going to be either 0, 1 or 2

```
0 male
1 female
2 everyone
```

I want to achieve the case where `_gender` is everyone, then I want the gender to be 0 or 1

But if it was 0 or 1, then I should match with users that are only as the variable

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE COUNTRY = 1
AND Gender = --"IF _gender == 2, then I need to get gender either = 0 or 1, else I get the value of the variable (to match 0 or 1)"
```

Comment: In T-SQL variables are denoted using `@` not `_`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to achieve here. We'll set the Country predicate aside for now and concentrate on Gender.

I understand that if `Gender = 0` or if `Gender = 1` you want the same value returned in your result set.

But what's to happen when `Gender = 2`?

Are you saying you want all `Gender = 2` rows filtered out of your result set completely, returning rows only where `Gender = 0` or `Gender = 1`?

Or are you saying you want the `Gender = 2` results included in your result set, but that you want Gender to display as 0 or 1 (either randomly or specifically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Denote Variable starting with `@`.

Lets consider variable `@gender`

### If you want when `@gender` is everyone, then the gender to be 0 or 1.

```
select * from TABLE where Country=1 
and  Gender = (case when @gender=2 then 0 else @gender end)
```

### If you want when `@gender` is everyone, then the all type of gender from your table.

```
select * from TABLE where Country=1 
and  Gender = (case when @gender=2 then Gender else @gender end)
```

**For reference click below link**
[Code Reference Link **Click Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f516e285e751c5001576b9374b75bdc8)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
where country = 1 and
      (gender = @gender or @gender = 2)
```

Often `null` is used for the value to mean everyone.  In that case, you need to phrase it as:

```
where country = 1 and
      (gender = @gender or @gender is null)
```

Comment: Thanks, but here how can i know that _gender == 2?
gender = _gender is valid only where the _gender is not equal to 2.

Comment: @Scryptopath . . . Isn't "2" the value that you are using to specify that you want all (both) gender values in your database?